# In our Swift file, where do I import the swift module?

Tags: ios, swift, module

I am reading matt's iOS pragraming book, when I read here:

> Swift itself is defined in a module — the Swift module. Your code always implicitly imports the Swift  module. You could make this explicit by starting a file with the line import Swift; there is no need to do this, but it does no harm either.
>
> That fact is important, because it solves a major mystery: where do things like print come from, and why is it possible to use them outside of any message to any object? print is in fact a function declared at the top level of the Swift module, and your code can see the Swift module’s top-level declarations because it imports Swift. The print function thus becomes, as far as your code is concerned, an ordinary top-level func‐ tion like any other; it is global to your code, and your code can speak of it without specifying its namespace. You can specify its namespace — it is perfectly legal to say things like Swift.print("hello") — but you probably never will, because there’s no name conflict to resolve.

Such as, in my test `ViewController`:

```
import UIKit
//import Swift // here we can import Swift. it is okay

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
        Swift.print("hello, matt")  // where we import the Swift ?
    
    }
}
```

We can use `print` or `Swift.print`, I just want to ask, how apple implicitly imports the Swift  module ? and obvious, `UIKit`, we must import, if can implicitly imports `Swift` module, why there apple do not implicitly imports `UIKit`?

My confuse is how implicitly imports the `Swift` module?

Comment: Your quote explains exactly what you seem to be asking

Comment: @Alexander, I update the question, before is my lack of clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implicit import of the `Swift` module is a behaviour hard coded into the Swift compiler, exclusively for the `Swift` module.

Comment: if it true, my confuse is solve, and how can prove this? does there is a `doc` or official statement ?

Comment: Not that I know of. You can hunt around the [compiler source code](https://github.com/apple/swift) for proof, if you care enough to do so. In any case, this is a step that happens automatically sometime during compilation, the details of which don't really matter. It's not a mechanism you can use yourself to implicitly import modules, if that's what you're looking to do.

Comment: The `Clang` can detect the swift language grammar if is right, so when we create the `swift` file, if it below the `Clang`'s detect, I will hunt for the proof , then reply.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to Alexandex's, I finnaly find the [doc](https://swift.org/compiler-stdlib/#compiler-architecture)

And we can see `Clang importer`:

> The Clang importer (implemented in lib/ClangImporter) imports Clang modules and maps the C or Objective-C APIs they export into their corresponding Swift APIs. The resulting imported ASTs can be referred to by semantic analysis.

Comment: There is nothing here to suggest that this is how the Swift module is imported